# Unable to decrypt node js Text i Java AES-256-GCM getting Tag mismatch

Tags: java, node.js, encryption, aes-gcm

Am able to encrypt and decrypt node and java code individually but when trying to decrypt the node text in java getting Tag mismatch! Am trying to encrypt and decrypt a simple `Hello World` text here

node js code i have :

```
const buffer = require('buffer');
const crypto = require('crypto');

// Demo implementation of using `aes-256-gcm` with node.js's `crypto` lib.
const aes256gcm = (key) => {
  const ALGO = 'aes-256-gcm';

  // encrypt returns base64-encoded ciphertext
  const encrypt = (str) => {
    // Hint: the `iv` should be unique (but not necessarily random).
    // `randomBytes` here are (relatively) slow but convenient for
    // demonstration.
    const iv = new Buffer(crypto.randomBytes(16), 'utf8');
    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(ALGO, key, iv);

    // Hint: Larger inputs (it's GCM, after all!) should use the stream API
    let enc = cipher.update(str, 'utf8', 'base64');
    enc += cipher.final('base64');
    console.log(enc);
    return [enc, iv, cipher.getAuthTag()];

  };

  // decrypt decodes base64-encoded ciphertext into a utf8-encoded string
  const decrypt = (enc, iv, authTag) => {
    const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(ALGO, key, iv);
    decipher.setAuthTag(authTag);
    let str = decipher.update(enc, 'base64', 'utf8');
    str += decipher.final('utf8');

    return str;
  };

  return {
    encrypt,
    decrypt,
  };
};

const KEY = new Buffer('fTjWnZr4u7x!z%C*F-JaNdRgUkXp2s5v', 'utf8');

const aesCipher = aes256gcm(KEY);

const [encrypted, iv, authTag] = aesCipher.encrypt('Hello World');
const decrypted = aesCipher.decrypt(encrypted, iv, authTag);

console.log(decrypted); // 'hello, world'
```

And the java code i have :

```
private final static int GCM_IV_LENGTH = 12;
private final static int GCM_TAG_LENGTH = 16;
private static String decrypt(String encrypted, SecretKey skey) throws Exception {
    byte[] decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encrypted);

    byte[] iv = Arrays.copyOfRange(decoded, 0, GCM_IV_LENGTH);

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
    GCMParameterSpec ivSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(GCM_TAG_LENGTH * Byte.SIZE, iv);
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skey, ivSpec);

    byte[] ciphertext = cipher.doFinal(decoded, GCM_IV_LENGTH, decoded.length - GCM_IV_LENGTH);

    String result = new String(ciphertext, "UTF8");

    return result;
}
```

The main method of the java execution code is

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String byte_key="fTjWnZr4u7x!z%C*F-JaNdRgUkXp2s5v";
    SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(byte_key.getBytes(), "AES");        
    System.out.println("foo "+ decrypt("1cbKXSnEWixxFi0=", key));

}
```

I think i am missing something here

Comment: In both codes the same IV/nonce must be used. For GCM the length should be `12` bytes. This is the case in the Java, but not in the NodeJS code. Furthermore, `encrypt` in the NodeJS code returns `3` values: ciphertext, IV and tag, while `decrypt` in the Java code expects a string (which is later Base64 decoded). You haven't posted the conversion! One possibility is to concatenate in the NodeJS code IV, ciphertext and tag in this order on a binary level and then to Base64 encode the result. Note: Java expects ciphertext and tag concatenated (in this order).